# Alphabetical order list in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make this type of list in my application as shown in image.]

[image]

How can I make this type of list and What is this control called any sample available.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called a `Jump list control`. You can find steps of creation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166297/Developing-a-Windows-Phone-Jump-List-Control) and [here](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/01/20/a-windows-phone-7-jump-list-control.html)